# Android Studio - Emulator: Warning:QStandardPaths:wrong ownership on runtime directory

Tags: android-studio, budgie, android-emulator

I am trying to run emulator on android studio, then there are warning on event log :

Emulator: Warning: QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio, 0 instead of 1000 ((null):0, (null))

The emulator did show but didn't show any display of android boot loading.

I am using Ubuntu budgie 18.04

Comment: please, Solution ...